# Use of ン in place of の

Tags: nuances, katakana, contractions

> 家**ン**中でさか立ちやって障子ブッこわして...
>   I was doing headstands in the house and wrecked the door and...

Presumably ン is a contraction of の. Why is it written in katakana? I guess it's adding some kind of emphasis; maybe "**in** the house" or "in the **house**"? Also, how would this sound in speech?

Comment: そういえばこれもカタカナの「ン」・・・→　[あたしンち](http://blogs.c.yimg.jp/res/blog-aa-a1/tsstc181/folder/1440299/06/38823706/img_0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common contraction in Western Japanese dialects. It's not emphasis. You could speak this in two ways:

> うちん中で・・・
>
> いえん中で・・・

This isn't typically written either (dialects are somewhat neglected in literature), so I would say the choice of ン over ん was on a whim.

One common (the only?) place I've heard this used in Standard Japanese is before [家]{ち}, in sentences like:

> [俺]{おれ}ん[家]{ち}来いよ

or after someone's name:

> [大助]{だいすけ}ん家で・・・

Note that in general, the easiest place to do this contraction is before other 「な」 row words, like 中 above.

Comment: The "Western dialects" part is totally incorrect.  Hardly an hour passes without hearing the の-to-ん contraction in Eastern Japan as well.

Comment: 「頭ん中」「腹ん中」「電車ん中」とか、関東で言いません？「大助んとこ」「ここんとこ」「そこんとこ」とかも。。

Comment: That makes sense. Dialect similarities radiate out from the ancient capitals in roughly equal distances. For instance, ばってん （same meaning as けど）can be heard in far west and far east dialects, but not in the central Japan.

Comment: @choco 言うね、確かに。I'm saying that in Standard, the use of ん is limited to certain fixed patterns, whereas in dialects that transformation can be applied to any use of の.